# Tutorials for Mobile Services for Xamarin.Forms - get device location

Tags: xamarin.forms, location-services

I am looking for instructions on using Mobile Services for Xamarin.Forms? I am especially interested in how to get the device's current location. I know that there is sample code here, https://github.com/aritchie/acr-xamarin-forms, that showcases everything that you can do with the library, the only problem being it is way too complicated for a newbie to understand, and there are no comments

Links to any comprehensive tutes or sample code with comments would be appreciated. I have searched but have not come up with anything good.

Cheers

Comment: I agree; the code of aritchie I believe has what is needed, but it's hard to follow if you're starting like you and me.  Where you able to get through the code?

Answer (score 4):

There are a good set of examples for learning **Xamarin.Forms** with some descriptions at the following link *http://blog.falafel.com/learning-xamarin/*.

With **Xamarin.Forms** being rather new you will have to search around for good snippets etc however.

There are a number of projects for **Xamarin.Forms** in *https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples*.  Try to looking at the following two for easier to understand short examples in **Xamarin.Forms**:-

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/FormsGallery

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/XAMLSamples

The examples are short enough that should help you to learn from them.

There is a *specific map related example* at the following that also *shows your current location on a map* that you may like to look at further also:-

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/8b9bbe853263f1eb29faca499619b0b757d8fbfd/WorkingWithMaps

Run the applications, make small modifications and experiment - a great way to learning.

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks for the advice Pete, I have all of the sample code and can work most of it out, I hadn't seen the blog.falafel one, so I will definitely check that out. I am still having problems getting the location from Android back to the Xamarin.Forms code though, and the sample code supplied, while no doubt is great, is very complicated and hard to understand for a newbie - so still on the lookout for relevant tutorials if anyone finds any. Cheers

Comment: Sorry, but where in the sample map code does it show the user's current location? - I can only find some hard-coded locats - I must be looking in the wrong place - Cheers

Comment: Apparently in the 'Working with Maps' example there is a line **.IsShowingUser=true** that should display the maps user location, but it wasn't working for me in my emulator when i quickly tested it.  There is a Geolocator is the *Xamarin-Forms-Labs* that should help you getting a current location via code though, take a look at [link](https://github.com/XForms/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/src/Xamarin.Forms.Labs/Xamarin.Forms.Labs/Services/GeoLocation/IGeolocator.cs)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find out a users location via shared code, look at the Geolocator plugin from the component store. super easy to use